# How to use strcmp in C?

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm new to C programming, and I'm currently having difficulty comparing strings. I'm trying to use the strcmp function. Everything seems to be fine, but I get:

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

My code looks like this:

```
char main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    int answer1;
    int asnwer2;
    char argument[99];
    char str1[] = "ABC"

    snprintf(argument,sizeof(argument),"%s",argv[1]);

    answer1 = strcmp(argument,"ABC");

    answer2 = strcmp(argument,str1);

    print("%d\n",answer1);
    print("%d\n",answer2);
}
```

Answer 1 and answer 2 are the different ways that I tried. Also, when I `printf` the variable `argument` after the line `snprintf`, I get `ABC`

```
snprintf(argument,sizeof(argument),"%s",argv[1]);
printf("%s\n",argument);
```

It prints
`ABC`

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: You don't get the same warning for `snprintf`...?

Comment: @HansPassant Wow, I indeed forgot. Thank you

Comment: @DevSolar No, I didn't get the warning for snprintf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you included <string.h> in your c program?

Comment: Wow, I indeed forgot. Thank you